# Javascript only works with ip after page refresh, before refresh access using dns works

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, onload

I'm struggling with a weird problem.
All my document.ready functionality is working when using the web page by dns.
When switching to IP the functionality breaks, but starts working after a page refresh.

Have anyone encountered this phenomenon before?

I know this is vague and apologize beforehand.
Thanks for any help!

Update:
Script has been verified to be loaded at the time when functionality doesn't work

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a little bit of code? Is the JS in an external file? are you sure that its getting loaded every time?

Comment: Js is in external file, just verified that it's loaded. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Based on your vague question, the only POSSIBLE idea I can come up with is that some Javascript you have is now being referenced by IP address `http://127.0.0.1/scripts` and the scripts directory is only available via the DNS named `http://hostname/scripts`.

Comment: scripts have been verified using firebug to be loaded